# $\tau$ be a cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau$ be a cofinite topology on a set $X$ . Also, if $\tau$ is discrete then
1) $X$ is infinite
2) $X$ is non finite countable
3) $X$ is finite
4) None of the above

Comment: Please share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer, but please read what follows the proof.

If $\tau$ is the co-finite topology on $X$ than if $U\in \tau$ then $X-U$ is finite. Now if $\tau$ is also the discrete topology then for every $x\in X$ we have that $\{x\}\in\tau $ , So  $\{x\}$ is co-finte. i.e $X-\{x\}$ is finite. And from here it should be clear which option is true.

You are new here, so you should know that when you ask a question, you should explain it properly. You don't want people to wast time on understanding your question. And second, this is not a forum where you can just ask people to do your home work, we are here to make you understand. So you should tell us what are your thoughts about the problem, what did you try and so one. good luck